# Why is @font-face is not working correctly?

Tags: css, font-face

This issue has been well covered and in all honesty should be very simple which is why it's blowing my mind I can't find a solution

My folder structure is as follows

```
htdocs
  assets
    fonts
```

I can't work out if the fonts are the issue or if it's not accessing the files as I have been having issues with accessing files inside folders, for example my JS works on index.php but no other pages even thought they have the same footer.php include, it's very confusing

I have also tried using a forward slash in front but that makes no difference

Here is my code based on much time spent researching this issue

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Favorit Std Mono';
  src: url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoStd-Light.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoTrial-Light.otf") format("opentype"),
       url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoStd-Light.woff") format('woff'),
       url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoStd-Light.woff2") format('woff2'),
       url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoTrial-Light.ttf") format('truetype'), 
       url("assets/fonts/FavoritMonoTrial-Light.svg") format('svg'); 
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Favorit Std Mono', "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: What appears in your browser's Developer Tools (F12) windows' Network tab? That will show you the actual requests being made for the font-files.

Comment: must be a path thingy ... in a web environment, try start your local links with `/` so you know the path starts at the root ...

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, it's displaying 404 Not found on all the fonts and I just dont understand why as I'm linking directly to them

Comment: okay I found a solution by using .. infront of / before assets :)